# Why can't find the value in Java class?

Tags: java

Here is the problem, when I defined a interface like this:

```
package mypackage;
public interface Ainterface {
  int VAL = 6;
}
```

and then I defined a class like:

```
public class Aclass implements Ainterface {
  private String[] str = new String[VAL];
  public static void main(String[] args) { ... }
}
```

When I compiler the program, there show the error message: can't find the symbol "VAL".

symbol: VAL

position: Aclass

Comment: Make the variable `private` or something. If you don't provide a specifier, I'm pretty sure it assumes package-private, and `Aclass` could very well be in a different package

Comment: @DennisMeng No. All members of an interface are `public` and `static` automatically.

Comment: Ah, interfaces do it differently? Some food for thought for me I guess

Comment: It does compile fine assuming they are in same package, do you have classes in different packages? if so all answers below are not valid here.

Comment: If you remove the `mypackage` declaration, this will work just fine.  I'm pretty sure that your issue is with the way that you're using `package`.  Please post more code.

Comment: @Steve Could you tell me the difference between the two ways? Thank you.

Comment: @Steve If i don't remove the package, how to solve it in your opinion?

Comment: I would refer to Jason's answer.

Answer (score 6):

> When I compiler the program, there show the error message: can't find the symbol "VAL".

Is that the *only* compiler error message? If so, please `goto wtf;`.

If *not*, are any of the other compiler error messages equivalent to the compiler saying that it also can not find `Ainterface`? If so, your issue is simple. It appears that either `Aclass` is in a different package, or you intended for it to be in the same package. In the former case, you need `import mypackage.Ainterface`. The latter case, you need to put `Aclass` in the same package with `package mypackage`.

### wtf:

Can you please produce the smallest working example that shows the issue? Here's the problem: I have to work really hard to reproduce your issue, and it's very unlikely to be the issue that you're experiencing.

There are few possibilities.

a. `Ainterface` and `Aclass` are in the same package. In this case, there should be no issue.

```
Ainterface.java:  

package mypackage;

public interface Ainterface {
  int VAL = 6;
}

Aclass.java

package mypackage;

public class Aclass implements Ainterface {
  private String[] str = new String[VAL];
  public static void main(String[] args) { }
}
```

b. `Ainterface` and `Aclass` are in different packages. In this case, there *must* be an `import mypackage.Ainterface` import statement in the `java` source file for `Aclass`. In this case, there should be no issue.

```
package mypackage;

public interface Ainterface {
  int VAL = 6;
}

Aclass.java:

package myotherpackage;
import mypackage.Ainterface;

public class Aclass implements Ainterface {
  private String[] str = new String[VAL];
  public static void main(String[] args) { }
}
```

In both cases, the code will compile *as is*. Neither of these produce the issue, and they are the only two possibilities that make sense. There is a third possibility. Please tell me it is *not* this. You have two `Ainterface` defined, one in one package, one in another and `Aclass` sits in the same `package` as one of the definitions that doesn't define `VAL`:

```
Ainterface.java:

package mypackage;

public interface Ainterface {
  int VAL = 6;
}

Ainterface.java:

package myotherpackage;

public class Ainterface {

}

Aclass.java:

package myotherpackage;

public class Aclass implements Ainterface {
  private String[] str = new String[VAL];
  public static void main(String[] args) { }
}
```

This *will* produce the error. And, to be clear, this *can* happen on accident. Say you define `Ainterface` and put it in `mypackage`. Say you define `Aclass` and you don't put it in the same package and you forget to import `mypackage.Ainterface`. If you're using an IDE like Eclipse, you'll get an error message that `Ainterface` can not be resolved to a type and you'll have three quick fixes available: "Import 'Ainterface' (mypackage)", "Create interface 'Ainterface'", "Fix project setup...". If you accidentally clicked the second option, you'll end up in this case. But that's just silly, that *can not* be what you intended. So, help us help you.

Comment: Though theory is correct, I think if classes are in same package they compiled fine without explicit interface name. I guess OP issue is they are in different package and missing imports or something else.

Comment: Well, you're on to something. But if he's missing an import then the line `Aclass implements Ainterface` would be offending to the compiler too. And he didn't say that's the case.

Comment: I am not downvoter and very very rare I do that, I agree that Aclass implement Ainterface also should complain, there is something fishy.

Comment: @Nambari: Agree. *Either* OP is *ignoring* another offending compiler error message, or the last possibility that I explained in my answer is what is going on. I see no other way.

Answer (score 1):

You should refer VAL in a static way as all the variables defined in an interface is by default `public`, `static` and `final`. This should work:

```
  private String[] str = new String[Ainterface.VAL];
```

Comment: This is *not* the issue. Put them in the same package xor put them in different packages and have `Aclass` import `mypackage.Ainterface` and in *either* case it will [compile just fine as-is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18094215/45914).

Answer (score 1):

An interface can contain constant declarations in addition to method declarations. All constant values defined in an interface are implicitly **public, static, and final**. Once again, these modifiers can be omitted. Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html) for more details.

So in order to access it use `Ainterface.VAL`(Since variables defined in interface are static).

```
private String[] str = new String[Ainterface.VAL];
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine if present in same package but if you want to that files to be in different package then you can do either of things.

**Option 1:**

```
Import mypackage;
```

in `Aclass.java` file

**Option 2:** 
Or change `VAL` with `Ainterface.VAL` then statement become

```
private String[] str = new String[Ainterface.VAL];
```

Comment: If `import mypackage` were the issue, then the line `Aclass implements Ainterface` would be offending line.

Comment: @jason yes both lines gives error.but I tried every aspects when you import package then you can accesss Val without error. And I agreed with your ans and explanation. This is the only case when he get an error. So +1 for that

Comment: Right, that's my point. Either both lines offend, in which case the fix is *trivial*, or neither do except in a very weird case like I outlined in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18094215/45914).